# Inject log object in Grails class outside of grails-app

Tags: logging, grails, groovy, dependency-injection

I have a class in src/groovy in my grails project.

How do i make a log field that gets injected with the correct logger for that class ?

Is there a commons logging or just log4j in grails ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'd add it just like a regular Java class:

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass()) // log4j
```

or

```
Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass()) // commons logging
```

Comment: This is how i solved it ATM, but stil means that my class is tied to the logging system even when the logging beans of the entire application get changed.

Answer (score 49):

### Grails 1.X

A more Groovy way to do the same thing is:

```
private static log = LogFactory.getLog(this)
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `this` in a static context refers to the `Class` object, so the line above can be copy-pasted from one class to another without modification.

### Grails 2.X

Use the [@Log4j](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/logging/Log4j.html) annotation introduced in Groovy 1.8. This will add a `log` property

```
import groovy.util.logging.Log4j
@Log4j 
class MyClass {

  def doIt() {
    log.info 'hello'
  }
}
```

A nice benefit of using the annotation is that the logger automatically converts calls such as this:

```
log.info 'hello'
```

to:

```
if (log.isInfoEnabled() {
  log.info 'hello'
}
```

Comment: Cannot work: this is not available at the time of initializing the static field

Comment: It does work, because in Groovy `this` in a static context refers to the Class object. Obviously this is a difference between Java and Groovy. Try it out if you don't believe me :)

Comment: I would assume the package would be org.slf4j.LoggerFactory, is this correct?

Comment: No, that's the log4J LogFactory

Comment: For completeness and correctness, we need to add the 'import' statement and '@Log4J' is actually '@Log4j'. I can confirm that it works in a class in /src/groovy with Grails 2.2.2:
    import groovy.util.logging.Log4j
    @Log4j
    class MiscUtils {...log.info "m: ${m}"...}

Comment: For 1.x versions, don´t forget to `import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard Log4j's new Logger(getClass()) worked, but logged 'java.lang.Class' for me (using Grails 1.2.1). This problem went away with the Sublog plugin and @WithLog. See http://www.grails.org/plugin/sublog. This plugin also does not make Trace become Debug and Fatal Error...!

Comment: Hi Olivier, this question is kind of stale by now, since it was meant for grails 1.0.4.

Comment: This is not mentioned in the question, though. My answer still stands! :-)